# Kivy. Strange view on android

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

On Android(only) device all widgets are situated on left-bottom corner and have small sizes.I tried use size_hint and pos_hint and FloatLayout, but there is no results.What's wrong?

This is .kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0.0
#:import win kivy.core.window

Widget:

    Label:
        id:TopLabel
        text:'Eye verification app'
        width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(40)
        height: '48dp'
        pos: 40,40
        bold:True
        color:1,0,0,1

    Button:
        id:registrateButton
        on_release:

            app.take_picture('registrate')
        text: 'Registrate'
        width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(40)
        height: '48dp'
        pos: 40,160
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your app looks like on my PC:

[image: On PC]

And this is how it looks on my Android device:

[image: On Android]

I'm guessing that's still too small for you, here's a way to make the buttons bigger:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.0.0
#:import win kivy.core.window

FloatLayout:

    Label:
        id:TopLabel
        text:'Eye verification app'

        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2 # to react to the screen's size
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.4, "center_x": 0.5} # to place where we want it on the screen

        bold:True
        color:1,0,0,1

    Button:
        id:registrateButton
        on_release:
            app.take_picture('registrate')

        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2 # the same as previous
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.7, "center_x": 0.5} # top is a little lower

        text: 'Registrate'
'''))
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image: New PC]

On Android:

[image: New Android]